# PFQueryTableViewController limit

Tags: ios, swift, pfquery

I'm trying to set a limit on a PFQuery tableview controller but it's not working. I'm trying to make it so that it loads 1 cell, then another after pagination, and then another.

Here is my code.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject> {
    var query : PFQuery<PFObject>!
    query = PFQuery(className: "Products")
    query.limit = 1

    return query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a limit to your query, set the `objectsPerPage` property of your `PFQueryTableViewController` to 1.

Comment: do I put the objectsPerPage in viewDidLoad

Comment: How does it not work? Does it load more items? Does it fail to load?

Comment: when I press load more, it crashes and gives me this error. 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 0 sections after the update'

Comment: all Im trying to do is limit the objects loaded to make sure the load time isn't too long, so I want to load the first 5 objects, then a user can load more if they want

Comment: Unless you have objects with a LOT of data, it won't make much difference if you pull 5 or 25 objects (25 is the default). That exception you're seeing looks like a problem within `PFQueryTableViewController` though.

Comment: im pulling a lot of data, I mean a lot. so do I just set the limit and skip to 5

Comment: and will that help me fix it

Comment: I basically have a cell with 20 objects of text being pulled and one image. I think thats a lot of data. Now first off, should I limit and skip it to just 5. And after the first 5 are loaded, will it automatically pull another 5 or will it show a load more button